# Why is Firefox accessing my .viminfo and .bash_history files?

Tags: firefox, privacy

Under Ubuntu 22.04, AppArmor is active by default and configured to check all file accesses of Firefox and LibreOffice. Firefox is packaged as a "snap". When I look which file accesses AppArmor rejected, I get this list:

```
# grep audit /var/log/kern.log | grep DENIED | fgrep snap.firefox.firefox \
  | grep 'operation="open"' | sed -e 's/.*name="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/' | sort -u
/etc/fstab
/home/bruno/.bash_history
/home/bruno/.gtkrc-2.0
/home/bruno/.lesshst
/home/bruno/.python_history
/home/bruno/.python_history-36761.tmp
/home/bruno/.viminfo
/home/bruno/.viminfo.tmp
/home/bruno/.xsession-errors
/run/mount/utab
```

Why is Firefox trying to access my `.viminfo`, `.bash_history`, `.python_history`, and `.lesshst` files? These files contain most private information about my habits.

I can understand the attempts to access to `.gtkrc-2.0` (Gtk configuration) and `.xsession-errors` (Xorg errors).

I have checked the Firefox plugins and addons: only trustable ones.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any code inside Firefox that does this and this does not reproduce for me with [Mozilla's own build](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/download/thanks/). But Firefox itself relies on GTK, Glib, FreeType, Pango, DBus, X11/Wayland, etc... libraries, so the offending code could originate from a lot of places.

It may be worthwhile to compare Mozilla's build to the Ubuntu Snap package to identify whether this is specific to the Snap.

Comment: I am now using the non-snap package of Firefox. (The snap version's behaviour regarding download directories was unbearable.) It does not leave any traces in `/var/kern/log`. But this only means that there are no AppArmor rules for `firefox`. If this Firefox build accesses `/home/bruno/.bash_history`, I would not know it.